# How to import mysql data into cassandra database for php code?

Tags: cassandra

I am completely new to Cassandra and I need to import a massive amount of data from Mysql Server into Cassandra. I cannot seem to find a demo on how to import into Cassandra for PHP code .

Please help me!!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [PHP Driver](https://github.com/datastax/php-driver) to insert to Cassandra

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, it seems that you have 2 actions:

- you already have data in the database that should be migrated to Cassandra, there is an article that explains the how-to and most common caveats [here](https://academy.datastax.com/mysql-to-cassandra-migrations)
- Once that the data is migrated, interact with it with PHP, you can use the PHP Driver as @Ido mentioned, also you can look at this [tutorial](https://academy.datastax.com/resources/getting-started-apache-cassandra-and-php)